# Does mongo use an index when doing a wildcard, case insensitive, regular expression search?

Tags: mongodb

I've seen a few discussions about how it doesn't, but some of those discussions are a few years old.

I'm basically trying to figure out the database cost of allowing my users to type in a portion of a last name and find matching names, regardless of the case of the name in the database, and with wildcards effectively on the front AND back of the query term.
So a query for ers should return names like:

- Ers
- ERS
- ERSO
- anders
- anderson

etc.

Am I interpreting this explain correctly, in that it is certainly utilizing my index on lastName?

```
db.chart.find({"lastName": /ers/i}).explain()
{
"cursor" : "BtreeCursor lastName_1",
"isMultiKey" : false,
"n" : 1246,
"nscannedObjects" : 1246,
"nscanned" : 56467,
"nscannedObjectsAllPlans" : 1246,
"nscannedAllPlans" : 56467,
"scanAndOrder" : false,
"indexOnly" : false,
"nYields" : 441,
"nChunkSkips" : 0,
"millis" : 55,
"indexBounds" : {
    "lastName" : [
        [
            "",
            {

            }
        ],
        [
            /ers/i,
            /ers/i
        ]
    ]
},
"server" : "servername:27017",
"filterSet" : false
```

}

Also, my index is "ascending", not "text"

Some suggestions I've come across also suggest that I store an UPPERCASED version of the field I want to search by to achieve the case insensitive search results, but as the above explain shows, it seems mongo is now capable of using an index for both wildcard and case insensitive searches... so storing the uppercased data is no longer necessary it seems.

Just looking for other people's thoughts on this.

Thanks.

Comment: No, not when you do case-insensitive, unless you have a [text index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/)

Comment: The docs on index usage for regex queries explains how they're used: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use.

Comment: Thanks @JohnnyHK I saw that, but the section on case insensitive regex searches http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#perform-case-insensitive-regular-expression-match (below the section on index use http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/regex/#index-use) is a separate section and doesn't specifically mention whether indexes are used when doing case insensitive queries...

Comment: @Wes For anything besides a case-sensitive prefix expression, all index entries must be scanned and compared with the regex.

Comment: So, even though the .explain() says it's using the index, it still has to visit every record... I suppose that's why it says "nscanned" : 56467

Comment: @Wes No, all _index entries_ must be scanned.  That's a lot quicker than having to scan all the documents.

Comment: Yes, understood.  So, the bottom line is that it will help to have the index in place, but every entry in the index will have to be looked at unless you are doing a prefix based case sensitive query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order for MongoDB to use the index on a case-insensitive search, use [`$text`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/) as you will need to create a [text index](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/core/index-text/)

```
db.chart.find({$text: {"lastName": /ers/i}})
```

If you have a single field index, MongoDB won't use this index on a case-insensitive search.

See open issue: [SERVER-90](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/SERVER-90)

Comment: But the .explain seems to show it's "using the index"... because if I remove the index, it just reports:  "cursor" : "BasicCursor"

Comment: Also, I get the same explain report when I remove the "i" from the regex, so it seems case insensitive or not, the explain is the same... ??

Comment: Yeah, I had the same issue with a project I worked on. It was confusing, but concluded case-insensitive didn't use the index (to search) as search times were at 40seconds down to 0.3seconds.